# unable to connect agent to puppet master node

Tags: puppet

error description:

```
$puppet agent -t
Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

In agent server:

```
[puppet@human etc]$puppet agent --configprint server
puppet
```

Comment: Do you have a DNS (or hosts) entry that respond for 'puppet' ? If yes, is your puppetmaster listening on the right interface ?

Comment: yes it listens on port 8140                                                                                                                   puppet agent --configprint masterport
8140..this moorning i tried to connect with root user using[puppet agent -t] and it connected/..could you suggest why i was unable to connect with sudo puppet user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an old question. Answering it for future folks who find this post and have the same issue.
the puppet agent MUST be run as root. 
sudo  puppet agent [commands]
will not work. Puppet must have root privs.
sudo  puppet agent [commands]
may or may not work. It OUGHT to work, but if your environment is not configured correctly, you could encounter problems.
$0.02